# Changing PATH to move from python 3.6 to 2.7 on Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, path

New to Python. Already have Python 3.6 installed, followed by 2.7.

To continue learning I have been following online courses that only appear to use Python 2.7.

I have tried following these instructions on editing my path, however I am unsure what to change and what the impact will be if I do this incorrectly (http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Is it as simple as changing \Programs\Python\Python36\ to Python27?

Comment: not as simple: there are file associations too. Best in your case is virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

To run python 2.7 on cmd you just need to change the path preiority from python27 to the top.
Control Panel/security system/system/advanced system setting(on the top left)/environment Variable/(Double-clic on)Path in variable system

Get path:

[image: Get path]

Set path:

[image: set path]

Now you can type python to run from cmd

Comment: Thanks. I have followed those steps but when I try to run python in cmd, 3.6 is the default. I have not removed 3.6. Do I need to?

Comment: just remove it from the path